# trying to create a deep array in python, able to get the output below line is executed in shell, but not when I run from the Program

Tags: python

My Code:

```
output =[]

[[[output.append("") for counter1 in range(0,len(Total_columns)+16,1)]for counter2 in range(0,deprication_range,1)]for counter3 in range(0,len(Total_data),1)]
```

Total_columns and Total_data are arrays which have their lengths as 21 and 2 respectively and deprication_range is an integer 7

please let me know if I am making any kind of silly mistake. This really beats me..I suppose I am doing something fundamentally incorrect which I am not able to identify..

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Ajay

Comment: What is the (incorrect) output you get, and what do you expect?

Comment: If you're confused by lots of `None`s, that's because the value of `output.append("")` is `None`. `output` `itself will change, but you don't use `output` as the element in your list comprehension, you use (the result of) `output.append("")`.

Comment: Hi Thank you for prompt reply..
no its not none... my desired output is [[[val1, val2..],[valm,valn..]],[[val1, val2..],[valm,valn..]]]

Comment: And what output do you currently get? And where do you get val1, val2 etc from?

Comment: Hello Evert, just gave sample values actually I fetch my data from a table and am trying to format it before reporting it. I have realized my error.. the output which I was getting was something like this ["","","","".............]
Cheers<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you wouldn't append to output inside of the list comprehension. so you can change output.append("") to just "" and that will run

```
output = [[["" for counter1 in range(0,len(Total_columns)+16,1)]for counter2 in range(0,deprication_range,1)]for counter3 in range(0,len(Total_data),1)]
```